# Lock/Unlock a github branch

Tags: github

How can I **lock** a github `develop` branch so that no one can merge PR (even if PR approved) until I **unlock** the branch? This is needed because I want to create a `release` branch, out of `develop` and restrict unintended merge until branch out. I went through branch protection rules and it does not serve my purpose i.e. there is no option that says lock/unlock a branch.

**Explanation:**
I have a `develop` branch and developers can create feature branches from `develop` branch and raise PRs, and once PRs get reviewed and get approval, developers can merge their PRs to develop. Now, I want to create a `release` branch from `develop` so I want to restrict all the developers to be able to merge their PRs to `develop` branch even if PRs got approved. It may take a few days to create a `release` branch because whatever code I have in `develop` branch, I want to test and by this testing time, I want to lock the `develop` branch, so that no one can merge their PRs into develop branch. Once testing successfully done, I will create a `release` branch from develop and I will then unlock the `develop` branch, so that, from now on developers can merge their PRs to develop branch.

Comment: Why do merge restrictions not provide this exact solution?

Comment: You can protect branches in github, but it has no effect on local repos. Github cannot control local repos/branches at all

Comment: guys, I never said it is a local branch.

Comment: Sorry, I read a comment as though it was yours. My mistake. Still, I'm not clear on the problem.

Comment: If you create a *new* release branch from `develop`, no further additions to `develop` will appear in your release branch. There's no need to lock `develop`; just don't provide write access to the release branch.

Comment: FYI: bitbucket has an option that restricts all kinds of changes in a branch. In the branch permission, you can enable `Prevent all changes`

Comment: @han Based on your edit, you just need to fix your process. Create a release branch as soon as you're ready to start stabilizing for release, then stabilize in the release branch. Later, any stabilization changes made in the release branch need to be integrated back downstream so you don't have regressions. This is a very common pattern if you're following GitFlow.

Comment: @DanielMann we follow GitFlow with some adjustment. we cannot create a release branch until the intended features QA test in dev environment and there is a gap(2-3 days) between the features being merged & QA testing complete. That's why I want to lock develop branch for those 2-3 days for QA completion.  Seems like there is no essay option in github unlike bitbucket/azure devops.

Comment: I think the explanation on this question is muddying the waters here, since that specific reason wouldn't require a "lock" (because you can create a release branch from any commit you wish). Ultimately *why* you want to lock the branch shouldn't matter, it's a good question to ask what an easy way would be to temporary block PRs from getting completed when branch protection is already on. (For example, if 20 people can complete PRs, you could change the list of people to 1 person, but I'm not sure if that's an "easy" way to enable a lock for a few hours and then put it back later in the day).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a branch at any time from any commit, there is no reason to lock an active branch and prevent people from working.

`git checkout -b <new branch name> <commit hash>`, then `git push`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but for our business case it does not apply

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not available in `git` itself. This can be handled by whichever server you use to manage the repo. See [Managing a branch protection rule @ Github](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule). You can set rules by branch name or pattern and require a PR to merge to that branch. You should also be able to set who can merge and other rules related to branch management.

Comment: "handled by whichever server you use to manage the repo" Not necessarily. Since it's not a Git matter, it depends completely on the server and the interface that it provides.

Answer (score 1):

Since Oct. 2022, you actually can lock a branch:

> ### [New Branch Protections: Last Pusher and Locked Branch](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-20-new-branch-protections-last-pusher-and-locked-branch) (Oct. 2022)
>
> #### Push protection enabled.
>
> This allows for branches to be locked, prohibiting changes.
> You can lock a branch allowing you to have a maintenance window and prevent changes, or to protect a fork so it only receives changes from its upstream repository.
>
> To use this feature in a branch protection rule, enable **Lock branch**.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/7575792/196246562-59b7b156-a180-4830-ae67-d202ec49f172.png?ssl=1 -- Screenshot of Lock branch with fork sync enabled]

So:

> How can I lock a github develop branch so that no one can merge PR (even if PR approved) until I unlock the branch?

The [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#lock-branch) does include:

> You can enable this setting to apply the restrictions to admins and roles with the "bypass branch protections" permission, too.